# rename files with rename command

Tags: shell-script, rename

Please advice what is wrong with the following command

```
find /tmp/dir -name "* *" -type f | rename 's/*/fixed_/g'
```

remark - I prefer to do that with one command not loop syntax

What I want is to rename all the files under /tmp/dir , by adding the name **fixed_** before each file

For example ( the files )

```
Fevc.txt
Ddve.txt
```

Should rename to:

```
fixed_Fevc.txt
fixed_Ddve.txt
```

Comment: Does your `find` command even give output? It is perfectly find to omit `-name` here.

Comment: I get from the output - call: rename from to files... ( but files not renamed )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Temporary note: there is something wrong - the rename pattern does not handle filenames with path; I'm working on a fix*

What is wrong in your command is two things:

`find /tmp/dir -name "* *" -type f | rename 's/*/fixed_/g'`

- The `-name "* *"` matches only file names with a space in it - that's not what you want, right?

  - the solution is to just leave it out; We do not want to exclude files matching some name - we want all.
- The `rename` pattern is wrong in two ways

  - you used a shell glob pattern, but it needs to be a regular expression, in short a regex (It can be some general perl expression - let's ignore it and use only `s///g`)
  - the fixed pattern would match the complete name, and replace it with `fixed_`. You want to "replace" the "first 0 characters" with `fixed_`, technically. That's the start of the line, matched with `^`. We can leave out the `g` because there is only one replacement needed per line.

Putting it together, it looks like this:

**`find /tmp/dir -type f | rename 's/^/fixed_/'`**

Comment: +1 for the (overdue) `rename 's/^/fixed_/'` "correction". The OP clearly has a `*` in the regex which is indeed highly unsafe, as whenever one wants something to get *prepended* (like the "fixed_" in this example), one must use `/^/` __not__ `/*/`.

Comment: A post to guide you with Perl's rename: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574

Answer (score 1):

It seems your system features the older version of [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) that doesn't use regular expressions. You can rename your files with

```
cd /tmp/dir/
for f in *\ * ; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && mv "$f" fixed_"$f"
done
```

(untested)

For the [rename](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html) command with regex support, you have to change the regular expression: `*` needs something to operate on, it means "repeat the previous thing zero or more times". You don't want to replace anything, you want to prepend, so use `^` which stands for the beginning of the string:

```
rename 's/^/fixed_/'
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's interested in a zsh solution

```
 cd /tmp/dir
 for f (*(.)) mv $f fixed_$f
```

where (.) means files only

A simpler case

```
 for f (*.txt) mv $f fixed_$f
```

Comment: [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv)!